# Appropriate way to check if not null and a number

Tags: javascript

I see all over the place that you should use the !isNaN function to check if a value is a number. That method has seemed odd to me though, because I have always used the following method which seems to check for null and a number, easily and quickly. Is there anything wrong with this method?

```
var num = getCookie('testnum');
if (+num) { console.log('num is not null and is a number'); }
```

Thanks

Comment: By "null", you mean "zero" ?

Comment: ok, I see what you are saying. A value of 0 would be false! So would the correct method be: if (num && !isNaN(num)) ???

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle The answer of your question in the comment is: No . Zero is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you guys really are much smarter than me when it comes to this stuff. After doing some more research, it seems apparent that determining whether a value is a number is something kind of esoteric to normal everyday programmers like me. For that reason, I decided to resort to jQuery and let the professionals handle a matter as complex as this. Thank you for your time. Here is my solution which I hope is valid, Thanks.

```
function isNum(val) {
    return $.isNumeric(val);
}

function isNumNotZero(val) {
    return ($.isNumeric(val) && +val != 0);
}
```

Comment: Include jQuery for check Number ... it's really great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to check if a string contains a literal js number (and nothing else), then yes, there's a problem :

```
var num = "0";
```

it can be fixed by testing

```
if (num==+num) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(num))) {
        console.log('This is a number');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best methods to check if this is number it's using `isFinite()` and `isNaN()` methods. Also not forgot about Object checking.

```
function isNumber(value) {
    return (
        Object.prototype.toString.call(value) == '[object Number]' &&
        isFinite(value) && 
        !isNaN(value)

    )
}
```

Comment: In this way ```isNumber(null)``` give you false.

Comment: You're right, forgot about this. First of all we checking that this is Number and only then check other.

Comment: What about `alert(typeof value)` instead of `Object.protoyp..`?

Comment: @reporter this is not a correct way to check type of object. Try to make ```alert(typeof [])``` and you will get ```Object```. This is not correct.